# Frequency count of exact rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I have a dataset like below:

```
Col1.    Col2.    Col3.        Col4 
A        123      D            J
B        234      E            M
A        234      D            J
```

I need to add a 5th column that has frequency count of exact matches on just columns col1 col3 and col4 exactly.

Expected output:

```
Col1.    Col2.    Col3.        Col4.   Col5 
A        123      D            J.      2 
B        234      E            M.      1 
A        234      D            J.      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupby` + `transform('count')`:

```
In [70]: df['Col5'] = df.groupby(['Col1','Col3'])['Col2'].transform('count')

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4  Col5
0    A   123    D    J     2
1    B   234    E    M     1
2    A   234    D    J     2
```